# How do the Lorentz transformations for space/time Intervals work

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I recently made a post ([Second year relativity past paper question, disagree with solutions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/738132/second-year-relativity-past-paper-question-disagree-with-solutions)) about a past paper question I was struggling with. It got closed for being too homework-y. I will try and distill my question into more physics.

Assuming we are in the standard configuration. When I use the Lorentz transformation for space and time intervals:

$$\Delta x'=\gamma (\Delta x-v\Delta t)$$

$$\Delta t'=\gamma \bigg(\Delta t-\frac{v\Delta x}{c^{2}}\bigg)$$

My understanding is that $\Delta x$ means $x_{event \space 2}-x_{event \space 1}$ and $\Delta t$ means $t_{event \space 2}-t_{event \space 1}$. The ∆x′and ∆t′ only reflect the values of these same quantities but in a different reference frame.

The issue arises because, in a solution given by my instructor, it appears as though $\Delta t$ measures the time between event 1 and event 2, but $\Delta x$ measures the position between two unrelated events (event 3 and event 4). Is this allowed?

Comment: "Is this allowed?"  Allowed by whom?  You are allowed to use any notation you like.  Who would have the authority to demand otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

In the Lorentz transformation
$$\begin{align}
\Delta x'&=\gamma (\Delta x-v\Delta t) \\
\Delta t'&=\gamma \left(\Delta t-\frac{v\Delta x}{c^{2}}\right)
\end{align}$$
all the differences ($\Delta x$ and $\Delta t$ in one frame,
and $\Delta x'$ and $\Delta t'$ in the other frame)
are meant to be between the same two events $1$ and $2$,
like in the drawing below.

[image]

Anything else would be wrong or a misunderstanding.